# Buy USD with binance USD

Tags: cryptography, binance, binance-api-client

I'm actually if anyone knows how to use Binance API to deposit USD with debit card transactions/ACH payment. Unable to find this on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Card deposits are not supported by the Binance API.

One of the reasons might be security, as they might not be allowed (by a payment processing company or a bank for example) to accept card details from an outside system (over an API).